# Improving performance of google drive bulk upload through api

Tags: python, multithreading, api, google-drive-api, thread-safety

### task

I have some code here that loops over a data.json file which has the filenames of videos (50MB-2GB size). My goal is to upload all of the videos as fast as possible. My first attempt at doing this can be seen below **CODE 1**.

### CODE 1:

```py
import os
import json
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
import time
from rich import print
from rich.console import Console
import math


def upload_to_google_drive(filepath, filename, folderid, cooldown):
    credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('./credidentials.json ')
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    
    file_metadata = {
        'name': filename,
        'parents': [folderid]
    }
    
    media = MediaFileUpload(filepath, mimetype='video/mp4', resumable=True)
    
    request = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media)
    response = None
    while response is None:
        try:
            status, response = request.next_chunk()
            if status:
                # print(f"Uploaded {int(status.progress() * 100)}%")
                pass
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
            if response is not None and 'id' in response:
                drive_service.files().delete(fileId=response['id']).execute()
            return
    
    time.sleep(cooldown/2)
    drive_service.permissions().create(
        fileId=response['id'],
        body={'role': 'reader', 'type': 'anyone', 'withLink': True}
    ).execute()
    
    link = f"https://drive.google.com/uc?id={response['id']}"

    time.sleep(cooldown/2)

    return link

clear = lambda: os.system('cls')

console = Console()

with open("./data.json", "r") as file:
    videos = json.load(file)

skip = 0
only_get = -1

videos = videos[skip:skip + only_get]

count = 1
clear()
console.print("-" * 50)
console.print(f"[bold]Uploading [blue]{len(videos[skip:skip + only_get])}[/blue] Videos[/bold] Good Luck :)")
console.print("=" * 50)
with console.status(" Working", spinner="bouncingBar", speed=0.6) as status:
    for video in videos:
        video_id = video.get("vimeo_id")
        title = video.get("title")
        author = video.get("author")

        
        filename = f"{title} - {author}.mp4"
        filepath = f"./videos/{video_id}.mp4"
        destinationDriveFolderId = "1QD3CwHQ_Ig0MfonvlccUQU5C1mOxHcrL"
        cooldown = 15
        
        fileSize = round(os.path.getsize(filepath) / (1024 * 1024))


        url = upload_to_google_drive(filepath, filename, destinationDriveFolderId, cooldown - 1)
        
        video["url"] = url

        time.sleep(1)
        with open("./log.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write(f"({str(count)} / {str(len(videos[skip:skip + only_get]))}) ({str(fileSize)}) MB) '{title}' uploaded succesfully.")
        with open("./data.json", "w") as file:
            file.write(json.dumps(videos))

        console.log(f"[bold]([blue]{str(count)}[/blue] [white]/[/white] [blue]{str(len(videos[skip:skip + only_get]))}[/blue]) ([cyan]{str(fileSize)} MB[/cyan]) [/bold] [white]'{title}'[/white] [grey]uploaded[/grey] [italic bold green]succesfully[/italic bold green].")
        count += 1
```

After calculating upload speed and total file size (300gb), i fund it would take 30 hours uploading all the videos, so i took another shot at it using concurrent futures, which just kept on and kept on throwing ssl errors. Loook at **CODE 2** and **OUTPUT 2**.

### Code 2

```py
import os
import json
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from rich import print
from rich.console import Console
import time
import math
from datetime import datetime
import asyncio

# Create a single instance of the Google Drive service
credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('./credentials.json')
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

# Use a persistent log file
log_file = open("./log.txt", "a")

async def upload_to_google_drive(video):
    video_id = video.get("vimeo_id")
    title = video.get("title")
    author = video.get("author")

    filename = f"{title} - {author}.mp4"
    filepath = f"./videos/{video_id}.mp4"
    destinationDriveFolderId = "1QD3CwHQ_Ig0MfonvlccUQU5C1mOxHcrL"
    cooldown = 1

    file_metadata = {
        'name': filename,
        'parents': [destinationDriveFolderId]
    }

    media = MediaFileUpload(filepath, mimetype='video/mp4', resumable=True)

    request = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media)
    response = None
    retries = 0
    while response is None:
        try:
            status, response = await request.next_chunk()
        except Exception as e:
            if retries >= 3:
                print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
                if response is not None and 'id' in response:
                    await drive_service.files().delete(fileId=response['id']).execute()
                return None

            backoff_time = 2 ** retries  # Exponential backoff
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}. Retrying after {backoff_time} seconds...")
            await asyncio.sleep(backoff_time)
            retries += 1

    try:
        await drive_service.permissions().create(
            fileId=response['id'],
            body={'role': 'reader', 'type': 'anyone', 'withLink': True}
        ).execute()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while setting permissions: {e}")

    link = f"https://drive.google.com/file/d/{response['id']}/view?usp=sharing"

    await asyncio.sleep(cooldown)
    return link

async def process_video(video):
    fileSize = round(os.path.getsize(f"./videos/{video['vimeo_id']}.mp4") / (1024 * 1024))
    url = await upload_to_google_drive(video)
    video["url"] = url

    log_file.write(f"({str(count)} / {str(len(videos))}) ({str(fileSize)}) MB) '{video['title']}' uploaded successfully.\n")
    with open("./newData.json", "w") as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(videos))

    console.log(f"[bold]([blue]{str(count)}[/blue] [white]/[/white] [blue]{str(len(videos))}[/blue]) ([cyan]{str(fileSize)} MB[/cyan]) [/bold] [white]'{video['title']}'[/white] [grey]uploaded[/grey] [italic bold green]successfully[/italic bold green].")


clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
console = Console()

with open("./data.json", "r") as file:
    videos = json.load(file)

skip = 0
only_get = -1

videos = videos[skip:skip + only_get]

count = 1
clear()
console.print("-" * 50)
console.print(f"[bold]Uploading [blue]{len(videos)}[/blue] Videos[/bold] Good Luck :)")
console.print("=" * 50)

async def main():
    tasks = []
    for video in videos:
        tasks.append(process_video(video))

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())

log_file.close()
```

### Output 2

Most likely occuring due to thread safety.

```
an error occurred: [ssl: wrong_version_number] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2576) 
an error occurred: [ssl: wrong_version_number] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2576)
```

### Goal

My overall goal is to just upload 300gb (~1000 files) of mp4 files to Google drive as fast as possible in the highest quality possible.
Either i need to find a better approach than that of Code 1, or -- if Code 2 is actually non blocking and more efficient -- fix Code 2. Otherwise I'll need to find an alternative to both approaches that is as fast as possible, please recommend any. Additionaly, I'd like to speed up the process without reducing file quality. As when I tried using ffmeppg to do so,m it took 5 minutes to compress a tiny video so that would just make the upload progress longer

Thanks in advance.